# Is Schengen National Visa type D is same as Resident Permit?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, covid-19, poland

I am stranded in my home country (India) and trying to go back to my workplace in Poland. I have long term National Visa Type D along with work permit. Most of the rules given on Airline and Embassy websites say people with permanent or temporary **Resident Permit** are allowed to board the flights or enter the Schengen area.

**Is National Visa type D considered as resident permit or not?**

I know there are dedicated resident permits which we have to apply (like *Karta Pobytu* in Poland). However, I am confused with this condition. I have contacted Airlines, they said ONLY resident permit holders are allowed. Polish border guards say Resident Permit or Work Permit holders are allowed.

> ... the foreigners possessing a right to work on the territory of the Republic of Poland i.e. the foreigners entitled to work on the same grounds as Polish citizens, the foreigners possessing work permits, work permits for a seasonal work .... are able to present documents which confirms that they will start work shortly after entry to Poland,...

But none of them confirmed or denied whether I will be allowed. Can anyone help me with this matter?

Just extra information, I have already applied for a temporary resident permit (*Karta Pobytu*) last year which is already approved last month (I have scanned decision letter). However, to get the card, I have to personally go to their office in Poland and provide my fingerprints.

Answer (score 6):

The [US embassy in Poland](https://pl.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/) states exactly who can enter Poland (emphasis mine):

> ## Only the following categories of travelers will be allowed to enter:
>
> - Polish citizens
> - Citizens and residents of European Union countries who are transiting Poland en route to their place of residence or stay
> - Spouses and children of EU citizens and residents who are transiting Poland en route to their place of residence or stay
> - Foreigners who are spouses or children of Polish citizens or remain under the constant care of Polish citizens
> - Foreigners holding a Karta Polaka (ID card for those with a claim to Polish heritage through ancestry)
> - Persons with diplomatic status and members of their families
> - Foreigners who have the right of permanent or temporary residence in Poland
> - Foreigners who have the right to work in Poland
> - **Foreigners who have work permits**
> - Foreigners who drive a vehicle used to transport goods
> - Other particularly justified cases may be considered, but entry must be granted with the permission of the Chief of the Border Guard:
>   https://www.strazgraniczna.pl/pl/kontakt/1946,Komenda-Glowna-Strazy-Granicznej.html

So since you have a work permit, you will be able to enter.

But since your questions is:

> **Is National Visa type D considered as resident permit or not?**

I would say yes, but would not risk going to Poland only with that visa but would make sure I have something else that allows me to enter (like a work permit in your case).

Answer (score 3):

A National D-Visa is **not** a residence permit

- it allows for a visit longer that 3 months

A residence permit is **treated** as D-Visa insofar that it allows the holder to travel to **other** Schengen countries using the 90/180 rule.

Consulates generally **do not** issue residence permits.

A Consulate will issue a D-Visa based on their national laws

- often also to take up residence

With a D-Visa you can enter the Schengen Area (if not geographicly restricted) at any port of entry and transit to the country that issued the visa.